# CryptoJS DES (ECB) Encryption - Base64 encoded - not producing the correct result

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, des

We have a 3rd party supplier that has pointed us to https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/ to generate authentication tokens for their API.

This works fine but we're now at the stage where we need to generate these tokens programmatically. It needs to be DES format, ECB Mode, encoded in Base64.

We've tried the CryptoJS javascript library, but the results don't match the output of https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(text, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7

        });

        var finalEncrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);
        console.log(finalEncrypted);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tools4noobs](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) uses the PHP-method `mcyrpt_encrypt`, which works with Zero-Byte-Padding. The posted code uses PKCS7-Padding. To use Zero-Byte-Padding, the padding in the code must be changed to `CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding`.

But if Pkcs7-Padding should be used, then [Tools4noobs](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) is not a good choice because the padding cannot be set. In this case another option is [TxtWizard](http://www.txtwizard.net/crypto).

Another source of error is the format of the key. Whether this is also a problem here cannot be said, however, since the key generation is not shown in the posted code. It is important that the key is passed as a `WordArray` and not as a string. If it is passed as a string, then it is interpreted as a passphrase from which the actual key is generated, see [The Cipher Input](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

The following code

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("12345678"); // key as WordArray
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(text, key, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding // Zero-Byte-Padding
});

var finalEncrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);
console.log(finalEncrypted);
```

has the output

```
XokzhoQlYFGG7ZfTNqdvr0QGMsFF24oSZ5v+vsPDNlPA+GbJ2peAY/7pNhpOerOV
```

in accordance with the [Tools4noobs](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) output.

Comment: Perfect Solution thanks a lot!   I just needed the zero padding include  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/pad-zeropadding.js"></script>